# How to reset a multi-value checkbox using EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT in Craft 3?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-elementapi, events

I'm porting the functionality of an existing plugin from another CMS into Craft 3 through a custom Craft module. The functionality is:

When an option from a multi-value checkbox is checked on the "master" entry, the module will (1) create a new corresponding entry, and (2) reset the checkbox options on the "master" entry, so that no options are selected.

**Research**

I'm trying to be a good Craft citizen and have spent time studying the following articles. However, they either fail to mention what `event` they are using, or they end up using `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT`, or the solutions do not work with the current version of Craft (3.1.7):

- [Update checkbox value through plugin (Craft 3)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/update-checkbox-value-through-plugin-craft-3)
- [How to save a new entry with custom fields - Craft 3](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/how-to-save-a-new-entry-with-custom-fields-craft-3)
- [How to saveElement in EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT without infinite loop](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26772/how-to-saveelement-in-event-after-save-element-without-infinite-loop)
- https://craftcodingchallenge.com/challenge-6-the-chicken-or-the-egg

**Attempted Solution**

```
protected static function creatNewEntry()
{
    Event::on(
        Elements::class,
        Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
        function(ElementEvent $event) {

            // Ignore any element that is not an entry
            if (!($event->element instanceof Entry)) {
                return;
            }

            // Ignore entries that are new because they have no id
            if ($event->isNew) {
                return;
            }

            // Ignore entries that do not belong in section id
            if ($event->element->sectionId != 5) {
                return;
            }

            // Ignore entries that are not in the primary site...
            // This is important if you have a multi-site setup
            if ($event->element->siteId != 1) {
                return;
            }

            // Fetch current entry from db. Let's call this the master entry...
            $masterEntry = Craft::$app->entries->getEntryById($event->element->id, $event->element->siteId);

            // Get values from checkbox from the master entry...
            $checkboxOptions = $masterEntry->multiCheckboxField->getOptions();

            foreach ( $checkboxOptions as $option ) {

                // What should happen when a particular checkbox value is selected?
                if ( ($option->selected == true) && ($option->value == 'example1') ) {

                    // Create new entry...
                    $newEntry = new Entry();
                    $newEntry->sectionId = $masterEntry->sectionId;
                    $newEntry->typeId = $masterEntry->typeId;
                    $newEntry->title = $masterEntry->title . 'example1';
                    $newEntry->enabled = $masterEntry->enabled;
                    $newEntry->siteId = $masterEntry->siteId;
                    $newEntry->slug = $masterEntry->slug . 'example1';

                }

                if ( ($option->selected == true) && ($option->value == 'example2') ) {

                    // Create new entry...
                    $newEntry = new Entry();
                    $newEntry->sectionId = $masterEntry->sectionId;
                    $newEntry->typeId = $masterEntry->typeId;
                    $newEntry->title = $masterEntry->title . 'example2';
                    $newEntry->enabled = $masterEntry->enabled;
                    $newEntry->siteId = $masterEntry->siteId;
                    $newEntry->slug = $masterEntry->slug . 'example2';

                }

            }

            // Handle successful / failure of new entry...
            if (isset($newEntry)) {

                $success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($newEntry);

                if (!$success) {
                    Craft::error('Error saving entry: '.$newEntry->title.' ('.$newEntry->id.')', __METHOD__);
                } else {
                    Craft::info('New entry saved: '.$newEntry->title.' ('.$newEntry->id.')', __METHOD__);
                }

            }

        }
    );
}
```

This works great! However, there is no logic in the module that resets the multi-value checkbox on the master entry.

Whilst debugging, I have tried:

- adding `$event->element->multiCheckboxField = [];` on `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT` which resets the checkbox selected value from `true` to `false`, which is what I want! However, this does not work on `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT`. I can't use `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT` because it will require a user to save twice in the CP for my module to fire off the checkbox value.
- adding another static function, which saves the current event element however, this triggers an endless loop, which bounces between `isNew' => $isNewElement` on the `afterSaveElement` and the `saveElement()` in my module.
- Thought about using a hacky JS solution in the CP - which I don't want to resort to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of reflection;

I decided that resetting the checkbox values programatically on `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT` was not really needed.

I ended up using a JS solution that unsets my checkbox values from `true` to `false` on page load. Works very well. I added my JS through an Asset Bundle, which is loaded through my module. My Asset Bundle function looks like this:

```
// Load asset bundle
protected static function loadAssetBundle()
{
    // Load AssetBundle
    if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsCpRequest()) {

        // Don't show asset bundle on CP login
        if (Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity() !== NULL ) {

            Event::on(
                View::class,
                View::EVENT_BEFORE_RENDER_TEMPLATE,
                function (TemplateEvent $event) {

                    try {
                        Craft::$app->getView()->registerAssetBundle(YourModuleAsset::class);
                    } catch (InvalidConfigException $e) {
                        Craft::error(
                            'Error registering YourModuleAssetBundle - '.$e->getMessage(),
                            __METHOD__
                        );
                    }

                }
            );

        }
    }

}
```

The Asset Bundle JS looks like this:

```
// reset checkbox values after save
// Use the "Control Panel Body Classes" plugin to assign classes to <body>
if ($('body.class-set-by-cp-body-classes-plugin')[0]){
    $("input[name='fields[myCheckboxField][]']").prop('checked', false);
}
```

EDIT: This no longer works since upgrading to Craft 3.4. Visually, the fields are reset in the CP, but the reset values do not persist when the entry is saved